# Recording data into CSV files from DHT11

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, iot

Code below is designed so when the motion sensor is triggered it starts recording data from the DHT11. The data is then sent to a site called cayenne for data transfer. The issue is that the data being recorded and sent to cayenne is not being stored into the CSV file that is also created. It successfully prints the titles for each piece of data, however the figures being read are not being printed.
Uses Raspberry Pi 3B+, DHT11 Temperature and Humidity sensor and PIR motion sensor.

```
import sys
import os 

import Adafruit_DHT as dht
import cayenne.client

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# Added to deal with RPi 3B+
import platform
import re

import time 
from time import strftime 
import datetime

#Cayenne authentification info stuff
MQTT_USERNAME="4ff7bed0-f66b-11e8-a08c-c5a286f8c00d"
MQTT_PASSWORD="82e9cd4df60e9a8e864d0f4f80262322ad692068"
MQTT_CLIENT_ID="66751010-f7d6-11e8-898f-c12a468aadce"


client = cayenne.client.CayenneMQTTClient()
client.begin(MQTT_USERNAME, MQTT_PASSWORD, MQTT_CLIENT_ID)

# DHT sensor connected to Raspberry Pi to GPIO dhtpin. 
dhtpin = 3 #pin03 is BCM2; 2 in BOARD
# Pin for Pir sensor
pirsensor = 17  # BOARD11

#GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) #for using the WiringPi numbers
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) #for the Broadcom numbers instead of the WiringPi numbers
#GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(dhtpin, GPIO.OUT)  # Set dhtpin as an output

GPIO.setup(pirsensor,GPIO.IN) #Set pirsensor to input

# Sensor should be set to Adafruit_DHT.DHT11, Adafruit_DHT.DHT22, or Adafruit_DHT.AM2302. 
sensor = dht.DHT11 

# Set Duration in second between two mesures. 
period =  1

# Pir status
state = 0


#Create the log file in CSV format with header columns
with open('dhtpir.csv', 'a+') as f:
    f.write(" DATE & TIME \t " + " , \t"+ "% HUMIDITY " + " , " + "T(Celcius)" + " , \t" + " T(Fahrenheit),\n")


while True: 
    # Note that sometimes you won't get a reading and the results will be null 
    # (because Linux can't guarantee the timing of calls to read the sensor). 
    # If this happens try again!
    client.loop()
    # Pir 
    time.sleep(0.1)
    state = GPIO.input(pirsensor)
    if state == 1:
        humidity,tempC = dht.read_retry(dht.DHT11, dhtpin)
        #Convert from Celcius to Farenheit
        tempF = (9.0/5.0)*(tempC)+32

        print("GPIO PIR pin %s is %s" % (pirsensor, state))


        #Get the data

        if humidity is not None and tempC is not None:
        # Get the timestamp
            timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")

            client.celsiusWrite(1, tempC)
            client.luxWrite(2, humidity)

            # Print data to the terminal 
            print('{}'.format(timestamp),'\t Humidity: {0:0.1f}% Temperature: {1:0.1f} C'.format(humidity, tempC) , '({0:0.1f} F)'.format(tempF)), # print temperature in Celcius
            # Fill the previously created log wile with the sensor data in csv format
            # 
            with open('dhtpir.csv', 'a+') as f:
                f.write('{}'.format(timestamp)+ " , \t" + (repr(humidity))+"%" + " , \t" + str(tempC)+" C" + " , \t" + '{0:0.1f} F,'.format(tempF) + " \n"),
                #f.write(timestamp + " , \t" + (repr(humidity))+"%" + " , \t" + str(tempC)+" C" + " , \t" +  str(tempF) + " F\n"), # just a different formating output
                f.close() # not absolutly needed when using the 'with' syntax

        else:
            print('Exiting: failed to get reading.\n Try again!')  
            with open('dhtpir.csv', 'a+') as f:
                f.write('{}'.format(timestamp)+ " , \t Exiting: failed to get reading.\n Try again!")
                f.close()
            sys.exit(1)
        # Wait for the period in second between data reading
        time.sleep(period)


GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: What is the output in the file?

Comment: # Print data to the terminal 
            print('{}'.format(timestamp),'\t Humidity: {0:0.1f}% Temperature: {1:0.1f} C'.format(humidity, tempC) , '({0:0.1f} F)'.format(tempF)), # print temperature in Celcius

It starts with this piece of code. Prints the statement and does not fill out the data that is read

Comment: I don't know what that means. Please [edit] the original question to show the file contents

Comment: I will as soon as possible, no access to the Raspberry Pi at the time of writing annoyingly.